# Huge initializer_list compilation segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

```
    const QHash<QString, float> idfs = {{"the", 0.0023450551861261},
    {"of", 0.00258603321106053},
    {"to", 0.00375511856396871},
    {"and", 0.0040408455383457}
```

..293060 lines more

Compilation command:`/usr/local/bin/mpic++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG --isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64  -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -O2 -fPIC   -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/antiplagiarism.dir/src/idfs.cc.o -c /home/user/newanalyzer/common/src/idfs.cc`

Compilation result: `g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)`

Is it ok to have huge initialization list for gcc?

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

Comment: i doubt that input fits into floats

Comment: Could it be the reason for segmentation fault? Precise is not the issue here

Comment: for optimization "the" etc. should be QStringLiteral("the")

Comment: 293060 lines x 2?  If this is going on the stack that's going to be a .... what's the name of this site?

Comment: "Is it ok to have huge initialization list for gcc?" Apparently not. What sort of info are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: Why is segmentation fault ? is it gcc bug? maybe there are good alternatives to do this initialization

Comment: Good alternatives are called databases

Comment: for const data?

Comment: [Related info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023855/qhash-storing-large-amount-of-data). The OP there seems to have almost 10,000,000 entries in the QHash. Are you sure the segfault is because of this initialization. When you reduce the quantity drastically, do you not see a crash and does your program run properly then ?

Comment: this bug is not about runtime at all, it occurs on compilation phase

Comment: For large generated source files, it is usually recommended to stick to -O1, as you can easily hit one of the corner cases of -O2.

Comment: -O1 does not help

Comment: [`[implimits]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.35) suggests 16384 entries in a braced init list as a minimum for the implementation-defined upper bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug to gcc was submitted https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86118
Problem was resolved by using sorted array and binary search.

Comment: In that bug report, you failed to say if the issue is also present with more recent gcc versions...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to have huge initialization list for gcc?

Yes. It's not OK to have it so big that the system you build on runs out of resources. There are no limits inherent in gcc's architecture.

But this is static data and `QHash` is the wrong tool for the job. You should use something like [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#User_002dsupplied-Struct) with a user-supplied struct instead.

The input file to gperf would look as follows, in your case:

```
 %language=C++
 %struct-type
 %define class-name WordHash
 %define slot-name text
 struct Word { const char *text; double frequency; };
 %%
 the, 0.0023450551861261
 of, 0.00258603321106053
 to, 0.00375511856396871
 and, 0.0040408455383457
```

Using the gperf-generated code, you'd look up as follows:

```
double getFrequency(const char *text) {
  auto *word = WordHash::in_word_set(text, strlen(text));
  Q_ASSERT(!word || strcmp(word->text, text) == 0);
  return word ? word->frequency : -1;
}
```

Comment: I`ve already tried gperf, its running with '-f 0' option for more than 1 day, which is too long.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it ok to have huge initialization list for gcc?

No.

Instead, format the data into a JSON array of objects (or as an object with `"key" : value` pairs).  You can probably do this quickly with some simple regex commands (or modify whatever you are using to generate the init list).  [QT has JSON](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) support.

If you must has the data inside the program (instead of as a separate .json file for easy updating) then embed the file as a const char* definition.